# pd.to_datetime or parse datetimes won't work with my csv file (format: dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm:ss)

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I extracted the following table from my csv file

```
Date,Time,CO2(ppm),CellTemp(c),CellPres(kPa)  
10/08/2016,13:21:11,356.89,51.07,99.91  
10/08/2016,13:21:12,356.89,51.07,99.91  
10/08/2016,13:21:13,356.83,51.07,99.91
```

I researched the last couple of days and tried different things to make pandas read the `Date` and `Time` columns as `datetime`, but I just can't make it. Here are some of the things I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile)
print(df.dtypes)
```

I get:

```
Date             object  
Time             object  
CO2(ppm)         object  
CellTemp(c)      object  
CellPres(kPa)    object  
dtype: object
```

When I try:

```
df_2 = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']]) 
print(df_2.dtypes)
```

I get

```
Date_Time        object  
CO2(ppm)         object  
CellTemp(c)      object  
CellPres(kPa)    object  
dtype: object
```

So, now `Date` and `Time` are in one column (`11/08/2016 14:06:18`) (what I want), but not recognized as `datetime`.

When I then try:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_2['Date_Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S)
```

I get the error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-31-ace4ed1a0aa9>", line 1
pd.to_datetime(df_2['Date_Time'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S                                                            
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

When I try:

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse(df_2['Date_Time'])
```

I get (besides some other output) the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I also manually changed the dateformat to `yyyy-mm-dd` in Excel and tried the same things without any better result. I kind of think it must be a very basic mistake I am doing, I am new to scripting and would appreciate any help. Please apologize if my question has formatting errors I really tried.

Comment: You get `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` because you forgot a closing single quote in `format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S)`

Comment: Now I get: ValueError: time data '10/08/2016 2016-08-10 at 13:37' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' (match) :(

Comment: `df_2=pd.read_csv(file,parse_dates=[['Date','Time']]) ` works for me on your limited sample data, you probably have some erroneous data somewhere in your df, I suggest loading the df like in your first snippet `df=pd.read_csv(myfile)` and then do `df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Date','Time']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1), errors='coerce')` this will coerce any erroneous data into `NaT`, you can filter those out using `dropna`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is some wrong datetime or some value, which cannot be converted to datetime, so you can add parameter `errors='coerce'` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for converting them to `NaT`:

```
#31.11. does not exist
print (df_2)
             Date_Time  CO2(ppm)  CellTemp(c)  CellPres(kPa)  
0  10/08/2016 13:21:11    356.89        51.07            99.91
1  10/08/2016 13:21:12    356.89        51.07            99.91
2  31/11/2016 13:21:13    356.83        51.07            99.91

df_2['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['Date_Time'],
                                   format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                                   errors='coerce')
print (df_2)
            Date_Time  CO2(ppm)  CellTemp(c)  CellPres(kPa)  
0 2016-08-10 13:21:11    356.89        51.07            99.91
1 2016-08-10 13:21:12    356.89        51.07            99.91
2                 NaT    356.83        51.07            99.91
```

You can also check all problematic values by:

```
print (df_2[pd.to_datetime(df_2['Date_Time'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').isnull()])
             Date_Time  CO2(ppm)  CellTemp(c)  CellPres(kPa)  
2  31/11/2016 13:21:13    356.83        51.07            99.91
```